# Login dialog in c

Tags: c, authentication, dialog

Is it possible to create login dialog in C like this:

[image]

If it's possible, how can i do this?

Comment: you can do anything in c. you could try GTK, Qt, etc.

Comment: You'll need to use a GUI library with C. The C standard library does not offer GUI support.

Comment: Yes you can, with GTK for example. [I have a GTK3 Course material](https://www.youtube.com/c/MichaelB-GTK)

Comment: Please, be more concrete on what you want, as it's impossible to say what you need to do if you don't show what you are trying.

Comment: tinyfiledialogs is a single C file (cross-platform) offering basic dialogs (including an inputbox and a password box) http://sf.net/p/tinyfiledialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a GUI library if you want to achieve this using C. My recommendation would be [Qt](https://www.qt.io/). There are some great starter tutorials on their [site](https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/tutorial1-01.html)

If you would prefer not using a library and start from scratch then you will have to look into using the Windows API. However, that by nature won't be platform agnostic.

Hope this helps!

Edit: Qt isn't made for C, you will need to use C++ for the UI components. If you need pure C, please look into using GTK instead.